# Freeing a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a linked list struct on me, and I used a node struct to help me store data and know where each node is pointing to. In the creation of my list, I did this:

```
struct list {
 
 struct node *Head;
 struct node *Tail;
}

struct node{
  int val;
  struct node * next;
}
struct list create_list(){
    struct list new_list;
    new_list = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
}
```

Then, when I am trying to free the list that I malloced for, I did this

```
void free_list(struct list linked_list){

  free(linked_list);
}
```

However, I realize that I may have malloced wrong, because when you malloc, you need to assign it to a pointer. When I want to free the linked_list that I originally malloced for, nothing really changes.

I think this may be because the linked_list that I sent into free() is not a pointer, thus no changes have been made. I tried adding & and * to it, but I end up getting errors....

Any tips or help is appreciated.

Edit:

Fixed Typo on the struct list.

This is hw, so I cannot change the parameters of the functions, which is what is giving me a hard time freeing the linked list I made.  This is because the function free_list() cannot change its parameter into a pointer linked list, so I don't know exactly what to do.

I will also take note of when I am mallocing for the linked list in the create_list function.

Comment: Yes, you need to use pointers. `struct list *new_list = malloc(sizeof(struct list)); return new_list;` Please search for examples of linked list implementations to learn from them. They are all over the internet.

Comment: `Head` and `Tail` should also be pointers

Comment: The variable is `new_list`, not `list`.

Comment: The argument to `free_list` also needs to be a pointer: `void free_list(struct list *linked_list);`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the free_list function is fixed and the struct list parameter for it cannot be changed since this is hw. Also, I mis typed it, but yes I mad the nodes in the linked list as pointers.

Comment: Have you looked at existing implementations of a linked list? There are lots of them.

Comment: My linked List was, for the most part, implemented correctly. The only problem I am having is with the memory. Because the functions are fixed as this is HW, I am having a hard time freeing the linked list for which I malloced memory for in another function. Making the linked list is not my problem. I just need help figuring out the free_list function, where the linked list itself is given, not the pointer.

Comment: @Jr194: The `free_list` function better not be fixed because it's dead wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay for passing the linked list around by value rather than on the heap for something that small.

Is this more like what you want:

```
struct list create_list(){
    struct list new_list = { NULL, NULL };
    return list;
}

void free_list(struct list linked_list){
    struct node *next;
    for (struct node *node = linked_list.Head; node; node = next;)
    {
        temp = node->next;
        free(node);
    }
}
```

Thus freeing only the list nodes that were allocated with `malloc()`.